# AMQP.Net Lite with POCO classes

Tags: .net-core, amqp, azureservicebus

We are using https://github.com/Azure/amqpnetlite from the Azure team.

The description says we have to use the `AmqpContract` and `AmqpMember` attribute classes over the message bus like ActiveMQ.

We also have a lot of classes and we want to migrate to this Amqp library, but is it possible to use the serializer without those attributes and to use our POCO classes directly?

Another workaround could(?) be to serialize or classes into a json and use a wrapper class to send our payload:

```
   [AmqpContract]
   public class OurMessage
   {
      [AmqpMember]
      public string JsonPayload {get;set;}
   }
```

or should we avoid this workaround?

Answer (score 0):

The POCO classes as you mentioned are not supported right now. You will need to pick another serializer. Once you have the JSON string or a byte array, you do not need to define a wrapper class. Just directly create an AMQP message with the payload and get it back from the message body on the receiver side.

```
// sender
var msg = new Message(jsonPayload);
sender.Send(msg);

// receiver
var msg2 = receiver.Receive();
var jsonPayload = msg2.GetBody<string>();
```

Same thing can be done for byte array.

The AMQP serializer is designed to be simple and everything has to be explicitly annotated. For most cases this is possible and it helps to avoid double encoding and enable easier inter-op with other AMQP clients.